# mysql query to join tables

Tags: php, mysql

i have two table the structure of table is like this

```
TableA

id      location
1        Australia
2        Nepal
3        Australia
4        U.K
```

id is auto increment and unique

```
TableB 

uid   app      title    var1
2      music   reeedd    rfrwwdew
4      game     jejee     edeeded
2      game     efrfeded   ededede
3      book      ededed   dedee
```

please note that tableA "id" and tableB "uid" refers  to the same identification of users
i wanted to print the details such that users from nepal can only see the contents rfrwwdewas app is music only appears once.

so i used this query and everything was just fine and it printed the record as per my requiremnet but when i clicked on play it was escaping i noticed that it was not parsing (embeding java script) player

```
 $res6411 = sql_query("SELECT * from TableB as c join TableA as p on c.uid=p.id  where p.location='{$client['location']}' and c.app='music' order by rand() desc limit 3");



while($row6411 = sql_fetch_array($res6411)) {
    $outputmusic .= '<div href="'.$row6411['var1'].'" style="width: 520px;" class="item">
        <div>
            <div class="fr duration"></div>
            <div class="btn play"></div>
            <div class="title">'.$row6411['title'].'</div>
        </div>
        <div class="player inactive"></div>
    </div>';        
        }
```

the output i am getting is

```
<div id="playlist" class="playlist1"> <div class="item" style="width: 520px;" href="">
        <div>
            <div class="fr duration"></div>
            <div class="btn play"></div>
            <div class="title">Dheere Dheere Se Meri Zindagi</div>
        </div>
        <div class="player inactive"></div>
    </div><div class="item" style="width: 520px;" href="">
        <div>
            <div class="fr duration"></div>
            <div class="btn play"></div>
            <div class="title">DEKHA NE HAYE -BOMBAY TO GOA</div>
        </div>
        <div class="player inactive"></div>
    </div><div class="item" style="width: 520px;" href="">
        <div>
            <div class="fr duration"></div>
            <div class="btn play"></div>
            <div class="title">Saagar Kinare</div>
        </div>
        <div class="player inactive"></div>
    </div></div>
```

but i want to get this output

```
<div id="playlist" class="playlist1"> <div class="item" style="width: 520px;" href="uploads/userfiles/201206/1112_06_rhuak.01_TERE_NAAM.MP3">
        <div>
            <div class="fr duration"></div>
            <div class="btn play"></div>
            <div class="title">Tere Naam</div>
        </div>
        <div class="player inactive"></div>
    </div><div class="item" style="width: 520px;" href="uploads/userfiles/201206/114_50_q7n4k.25RAATKALIEKKHUWABMEIN.mp3">
        <div>
            <div class="fr duration"></div>
            <div class="btn play"></div>
            <div class="title">RAAT KALI EK KHUWAB MEIN</div>
        </div>
        <div class="player inactive"></div>
    </div><div class="item" style="width: 520px;" href="uploads/userfiles/201206/123_29_52l7b.15TeriPyariPyariSuratKo.mp3">
        <div>
            <div class="fr duration"></div>
            <div class="btn play"></div>
            <div class="title">Teri Pyari Pyari Surat Ko</div>
        </div>
        <div class="player inactive"></div>
    </div></div>
```

Comment: In your examples there are titles that don't exist in `tableB`. What exactly is the difference between the output you receive and the output you want?

Comment: title is the name of the song which is appearing in output but var1 is coming blank you can notice.

Comment: try to debug your code... print $res6411 and then check $row6411['var1']... If that's coming proper with expected value than no issue else check your sql in your db itself by printing query itself. Hope provided you idea....

Comment: Is there any error visible in the html source you can view from browser? As Kamal said, try a `print_r($row6411);` as the first line inside the while loop, to see if everything is ok. Otherwise, it could be some other error located in the DB structure (duplicate column values, maybe?) or in the way the query works on your DB. Or, of course, something i didn't notice :D